# Determine exponential generating function of the case given

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have a problem to determine EGF that show how many ways we can distribute r different people into n different rooms such that every room has at least 2 people and no more than 5 people. Of course, we know that this is a permutation case (and that's why it leads to EGF).

In ordinary generating function, we can manipulate the expression $(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)$ as $x^2(1 + x + x^2 + x^3) = x^2(1-x^4)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)$, but how about in exponential generating function which lets to
$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!}\right)$?

Could anyone help me? Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Using  the *coefficient of* operator $[x^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^j$ in a series the wanted number is 
>   \begin{align*}
> r![x^r]&\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\right)^n\\
> &=r![x^r]\frac{x^{2n}}{5!}\left(60+20x+5x^2+x^3\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{r!}{5!}[x^{r-2n}]\left(60+20x+5x^2+x^3\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>   Here we have $r\geq 2n$ since we need at least $2n$ people to arrange them into $n$ rooms.

*Comment:* In (1) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.

**Hint:**

- The paper *[Bracket notation for the "coefficient of" operator](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* by D.E. Knuth might be instructive.
- This *[MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580012/pascals-rule-i-dont-understand-why-we-can-do-this/2581108#2581108)* provides an easy application of the *coefficient of* operator.
- ... and *[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567436/how-can-i-prove-that-this-formula-is-related-to-the-binomial-series/2569361#2569361)* a somewhat more demanding.

Comment: Sir, could you explain more about operator $[x^j]$ and how do you get $[x^{r - 2n}]$  in line 3?

Comment: @Sukardy: I've added some hints. Regards,